# How to add PasswordEncoder into JdbcUserDetailsManager in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security, userdetailsservice

I'm learning about Spring Security and I want to add the BCryptPasswordEncoder at the JdbcUserDetailsManager.

This is the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {

        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(DataSource securityDataSource) {

        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();

        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(securityDataSource);

        return jdbcUserDetailsManager; 
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()   
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                .antMatchers("/leaders/**").hasRole("MANAGER")
                .antMatchers("/systems/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin() 
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")  
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")  
                .permitAll()  
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()  
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

}
```

I need the UserDetailsManager bean to inject in other class. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*I want to add the BCryptPasswordEncoder at the JdbcUserDetailsManager.*

Well, basically, you don't do it directly. The password encoder belongs in the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, **not in the `UserDetailsService`.** When you set the password of a new user using `JdbcUserDetailsManager`, the password you give to the `JdbcUserDetailsManager` should be *already encrypted*.

So :

- you can simply declare your encoder as a bean (I'd suggest using `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()`) ;
- it will be automatically used when authenticating users --- you simply need to configure your `UserDetailService`
- when creating new users, **you** need to manually encode the password before saving the user. So you can do it in the service class you use for this, where you inject your encoder.

You usually don't need to configure the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, but if you want to, the following code would do :

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager (
UserDetailsService userDetailsService ,
PasswordEncoder encoder ) throws Exception {
  DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider ();
  provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  provider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
  return new ProviderManager(provider);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use this class to create the UserDetails Bean

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

@Autowired
private com.fortsolution.schedmate.data.services.UserService userService;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("fine here murtaza");
    int id = Integer.parseInt(ssoId);
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    logger.info("User : {}", user);
    if(user==null){
        logger.info("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(""+user.getId(), user.getPassword(), 
             true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
}


private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user){
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for(UserProfile userProfile : user.getUserProfiles()){
        logger.info("UserProfile : {}", userProfile);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+userProfile.getType()));

    }

    return authorities;
}
```

}

after creating this class you will add these two method in your

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
@Autowired // <-- This is crucial otherwise Spring Boot creates its own
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

}
```

and

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authenticationProvider;
}
```